# Draw a box if perimeter of the box in the image is clicked

Tags: python, image, user-interface, drawable

My GUI is a slideshow of images. If the user clicks anywhere within the square that is already defined in another csv by it's left, top, right, and bottom coordinates, then a green box will show up. The yellow boxes are already present on the image and the user can click anywhere inside any yellow box for the green box to display. I currently have some images where the areas of two squares overlap. I would like to change it so that the user has to click on the border of the square in order for it to show up. I am having difficulty conceptualizing how I would change the:

```
    if t <= y <= b and l <= x <= r:
```

because that's where I think the change is needed.

[image]

```
    def clicked_evt(self, evt):
        x, y = evt.x, evt.y
        #the x,y coordinates of the user click

        # this is to retrieve the image from the csv
        image_row = self.get_current_image_row()
        file_name = image_row[CSV_IMAGE_NAME]
        image_data = self.loaded_images[file_name]

        for shape in image_data["shapes"]:
            # these are the coordinates of the correct boxes 
            l = int(shape["left"])
            t = int(shape["top"])
            r = int(shape["right"])
            b = int(shape["bottom"]) 
            if t <= y <= b and l <= x <= r:
            # if the mouse-click is within the boundaries
                # Draw the bounding box
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(l, t, r, b, tag="box", outline="green", )
                self.canvas.pack(expand=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call method `find_overlapping` of `tk.Canvas` to return what items overlap with the point you clicked.

> find_overlapping
>
> Selects all the items that overlap or are enclosed within the rectangular region given by x1, y1, x2, and y2. X1 must be no greater than x2 and y1 must be no greater than y2.

Example code

```py
from tkinter import *

def callback(event, item):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    result = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
    if item in result:
        print(f"Box {item} clicked !")

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg='green')
canvas.pack()

item = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 540, 380, outline="white", width=5, tag='box')
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, item=item:callback(event, item))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. This method is great for the whole area of the box but I would like only the perimeter and not the inside area.

Comment: You may not look or try the code provided in detail, it will find the box only if you click at the the border of box.